# Match charactes and whitespaces, but not numbers

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to create a regex that will match characters, whitespaces, but not numbers.

So `hello 123` will not match, but `hell o` will.

I tried this:

```
[^\d\w]
```

but, I cannot find a way to add whitespaces here. I have to use `\w`, because my strings can contain Unicode characters.

Comment: What *exactly* do you mean by *characters*; do you mean alpha characters as in `a-z`? If so what about using `[a-zA-Z ]+`?

Comment: OP wants unicode as well

Comment: match characters ? what does that mean? letters? symbols? everything is a character basically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Brief

It's unclear what exactly *characters* refers to, but, assuming you mean alpha characters (based on your input), this regex should work for you.

---

### Code

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/QT0Tas/1)

```
^(?:(?!\d)[\w ])+$
```

**Note**: This regex uses the `mu` flags for multiline and Unicode (multiline only necessary if input is separated by newline characters)

---

### Results

#### Input

```
ÀÇÆ some words
ÀÇÆ some words 123
```

#### Output

This only shows matches

```
ÀÇÆ some words
```

---

### Explanation

- `^` Assert position at the start of the line
- `(?:(?!\d)[\w ])+` Match the following one or more times ([tempered greedy token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30900794/tempered-greedy-token-what-is-different-about-placing-the-dot-before-the-negat/37343088#37343088))

  - `(?!\d)` Negative lookahead ensuring what follows doesn't match a digit. You can change this to `(?![\d_])` if you want to ensure `_` is also not used.
  - `[\w ]` Match any word character or space (matches Unicode word characters with `u` flag)`
- `$` Assert position at the end of the line

Answer (score 0):

You can use a lookahead:

```
(?=^\D+$)[\w\s]+
```

---

In `Python`:

```
import re

strings = ['hello 123', 'hell o']

rx = re.compile(r'(?=^\D+$)[\w\s]+')

new_strings = [string for string in strings if rx.match(string)]
print(new_strings)
# ['hell o']
```